# Can I set the name of the file in the content given to the response?

Tags: rest, api, jersey, jax-rs, response

I know, that I can set the name of the file returned by a header:

```
return Response
            .ok(content)
            .header("Content-Disposition",
                    "attachment; filename="+filename).build();
```

But can I set the name of the file from the `content` itself?

I am digging now in a large project, where the request data contain the target filename, and continue to contain it for some time. But when the content for the response returns, it already has no mention about the file name. And I don't understand - should I simply set the filename by a header, or to create some structure that would be used by Response file to create the filename.

I have looked into Response class and deeper, but I haven't found any attempts to read the filename or any structured data at all. But maybe I had missed something? For that passing that information into the classes that create the content had to have sense? Or not? (No, the current code responses with no filename). It is hard to believe in so stupid error in not so bad code.

Sorry, I am new in work with Jersey...

Comment: Not sure what is your question. Are you asking how to get file name from `content` ? what is `content` actually ?

Comment: The content is a byte array, according to Response.ok(...). But the string written there is json and of course, can contain any structured info. But sorry, if you don't know even the argument type of the function, how can you know how does it work?

Comment: LOL, I was not asking what is the **data type** of `content` instead I was asking what it contains (the value). FYI.. `ok()` accepts `Object` that can be `byte array` or anything else. I have worked on multiple restful app. 

PS : Don't judge someone immediately :P

Comment: @Ravi I am not judging :-). I have set a conditional sentence. if...then... Anyway, sorry for misunderstanding. Anyway, it seems, they simply have forgotten to return the name of the file through the header and no pass through content was supposed...